# script to add output from df -Ph

Tags: scripting, disk-usage

Would anybody have a quick script to add the used space out of a `df` command on Linux? I can do a RedHat rhel 6 but the rhel 5 switch for total is non-existent. I am looking to add the total of column 2 (after `dev/mapper` column).

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol00    7.5G   3.0G  4.2G   43%   /
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol02    2.0G   914M  969M   49%   /tmp
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol01    3.9G   1.2G  2.6G   31%   /home
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol07    992M   492M  450M   53%   /opt
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol08    4.9G   1.1G  3.6G   24%   /opt/patrol3
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol03    3.9G   1.9G  1.9G   51%   /usr
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol05    3.0G   469M  2.3G   17%   /usr/local
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol04    5.9G   934M  4.7G   17%   /var
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol11    496M   357M  114M   76%   /nsr
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol09    3.0G   428M  2.4G   16%   /opt/patrol3/perform
/dev/mapper/rootvg-LogVol12    14G    3.0G  9.5G   24%   /var/crash
```

Comment: Have a look at `man cut`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ df -h --output=used /
 Used
 1.5T
```